# What dpi resolution is used for an iPhone App?

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, ipad, dpi

I am working on a template for an iPhone App and was wondering what dpi resolution is used for it ? 300 or 72 ?

I am not sure and I hope somebody can answer me that question.

Comment: Note: This question was asked before iPhone 4 was announced.

Answer (score 84):

```
iPhones
iPhone 1/3G/3GS           320 x  480    163 ppi
iPhone 4/4S               640 x  940    326 ppi
iPhone 5/5C/5S            640 x 1136    326 ppi
iPhone 6/6S               750 x 1334    326 ppi
iPhone 6 Plus/6S Plus    1080 x 1920    401 ppi
  Without downsampling:  1242 x 2208    461 ppi

Except for the 6th generation (= 5th) iPod touch,
all the models are equal to their iPhone counterparts

iPads
iPad 1/2                  768 x 1024    132 ppi
iPad 3/4/Air/Air 2       1536 x 2048    264 ppi
iPad Mini 1               768 x 1024    163 ppi
iPad Mini 2/3/4          1536 x 2048    326 ppi
iPad Pro                 2737 x 2048    264 ppi

Apple Watches
Apple Watch 38 mm         272 x  340    326 ppi
Apple Watch 42 mm         312 x  390    326 ppi
```

Comment: Those numbers for the iPhone6Plus are only correct for the physical screen, but internally the screen the app deals with is 1242x2208 with a dpi of 461.  This is due to the downsampling done by the hardware to make the @3x buffer fit into the 1080x1920 panel.  Ref: [Curious Case of the iPhone 6+ 1080p Display](https://medium.com/@brucewangsg/the-curious-case-of-iphone-6-1080p-display-b33dac5bbcb6)

Answer (score 7):

[The original iPhone screen has a resolution of 163dpi](http://www.apple.com/iphone/iphone-3gs/specs.html) - use that in your template if you want to be able to print your screen designs at *actual size*.

For [iPhone4/4s, use 326 dpi](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html)

Comment: o.k Thank you. So you mean for images and icons, I should use 163 dpi ?

Comment: You should use 163 dpi if you want to, for example, print your template and view your screen designs at *actual size*.

Comment: No, use 72 dpi for any images, etc. that you're using inside your app.

Answer (score 4):

72 is the dpi for images

Answer (score 1):

Given the difference in the dpi between the iPhone and the simulator, you might want to use the raw pixel values of 480x320 for the iPhone screen.

Comment: yes, I have these dimensions. thank you anyway. By the way any good resources out there to download free templates?

Comment: There is a company/person who sells pads of paper that are meant as freehand templates, but I don't think that is what you are looking for.  Also, I think the company that does OmniGraffle has templates for the iPhone.

LMGTFY:
http://www.knoxing.com/2007/08/20/create-iphone-apps-with-knox-iphone-template/
http://www.osskins.com/main/joomla-mambo/commercial-joomla-15-template-iphone-template/2009/05/14
http://graffletopia.com/stencils/358
http://graffletopia.com/stencils/413
http://iphonedevelopertips.com/design/omnigraffle-iphone-stencil.html
http://konigi.com/tools/omnigraffle-ux-template

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  I find Interface Builder to be a good starting point and then I print and draw things by hand.  When I have some idea of what I want to do, I then get to work creating just the UI in Xcode, without the actual functionality, and anything that needs to be drawn, I do in Photoshop or other graphic tool.  I do envy those who can use OmniGraffle and other tools to create their pre-coding UX designs.  However, the amount of time I'd have to spend in OmniGraffle is best spent in Xcode and Photoshop (I hate/love/hate Photoshop).

Comment: awesome. Thanks guys for the resources and tips. I like OmniGraffle so far. Let's see how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone screen has 163 DPI, but I've found that images at that resolution appear too small in Xcode and Interface Builder. I recommend pretending that the screen has 72 DPI when making bitmap images for the iPhone, but remember that the screen has 163 DPI if you're drawing a ruler.

Comment: This has some history behind it: The original Mac was (approximately) 72 DPI, giving one-pixel-per-point; this is still the "native" DPI of a lot of graphics calls (so when I try to set a userpic in Adium, it sees my camera's "300 DPI" and shrinks everything); this is annoying for things that should be pixel-for-pixel (like iPhone dev, since iPhone OS ignores DPI information). Of course, PNGs use integer pixels per metre so can't represent exactly 72 DPI, so occasionally I see images which appear slightly off in Xcode; the fix is to remove DPI information entirely (`pngcrush -rem pHYs`).