# iOS, all 5 appstore screenshots width (with gaps)?

Tags: ios, app-store, screenshot

I'm trying to design a storyboard set of screenshots for my iOS universal app.
However I need to know the size of the gaps beetween all 5 screenshots for all supported devices.

I figure I'll design one big image and crop it.

However I don't know how to find out the size of the gaps?

EDIT: When I say gaps, I mean when you see all 5 screenshots together in the app store app or 2 shots together on the search results page, you see the screenshots with padding (aka a gap).

Theses are my current best guesses, but they aren't correct
 I have calculated, based on 15pt

5.5 inch display - 1080 x 1920 - 401 ppi - (iPhone 6+) - gap = 83.54

4.7 inch display - 750 x 1334 - 326 ppi - (iPhone 6) - gap = 67.91

4 inch display - 640 x 1146 - 326 ppi - (iPhone 5) - gap = 67.91

3.5 inch display - 640 x 940 - 326 ppi - (iPhone 4) - gap = 67.91

12.9 inch display - 2737 x 2048 - 264 ppi - (iPad Pro) - gap = 55

9.7 inch display - 1536 x 2048 - 264 ppi (iPad Air 2) - gap = 55

9.7 inch display - 768 x 1024 - 132 ppi (iPad 2) - gap = 27.5

Comment: Note that the "gaps" shown may depend on which App store is showing the screenshots (which iOS device or OS version or which Mac iTunes version, etc.)

Comment: Yeah, I was going to reply to your message with pretty much the same. I don't know if the gaps are consistent across devices (I'm pretty sure they're not). So I think a "best guess" would be the best approach here.

Comment: Hey Jules, did you ever find the correct/current values? Or have you found that those work well enough?

Comment: Those above shown in my edit work well

Comment: What about 6.5 inch displays?

Comment: And how were these calculations made?

Comment: It’s a guess based on how it looks in the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I've seen anyone ask this question :D

I am no designer.

-But-

I can tell you right now that each gap is about 20pt in width.
If you are a designer, and can transfer that to pixels somehow, good luck to you. Cheers. :)

EDIT:
I was double wrong.

I just double checked again the values. I attached the images now.

> The answer is 15pt.

Both of these are iPhone 6 images. And in my screenshots both of them have exactly 30px width. So 15pt = 30px for iPhone 6, as expected.
[image]
[image]

[image: 3]

EDIT: Just checked on fullsize iPad screen, it is 40px.

Comment: Can I ask how you know it's 30pt. Not sure how to translate that, no I'm not a designer.

Comment: Assuming your correct I could use these to find out what that is per device in pixels http://pttopx.com and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365112/what-dpi-resolution-is-used-for-an-iphone-app however I would like to know how you know it's 30pt.

Comment: Because if you Take a screenshot of it, iphone or iPad(meaning it's consistent),and compare it. the padding is the same as when we put a 30pt padding in code. It's just an educated guess. A better question is why in the world do you need this information :P

Comment: As mentioned, I plan to create a canvas with the device image sizes + gaps, then create a story with my screenshots and text. Then chop them up. Have you done these screenshots and calculated that it's 30pt or is that a guess?

Comment: I just edited my answer.
Launched my own apps, and the appstore and checked the gaps.
I was wrong, but this new answer is correct. It's 20pt.

Comment: Hey @NerbojsaNadj can you take a look at my calculations above. Now that I've drawn out the gaps, they seem too big. Perhaps I've misunderstood?

Comment: I think your right this time, however I'm going to give it a day or two and experience further and see how it works out. I'm using imagemagick to create the large image with the gaps. Cheers.

Comment: I've not convinced 15pt across all devices works, checkout iphone 4, it's wider than iPhone 6+ thoughts? https://www.evernote.com/l/AO-imAm2UHNLS5AVr9PGlnbUeW5dOz3j4OcB/image.png

Comment: I just had to do some major searching to actually find a iphone 4 fullsize screenshot with that gap in it. It's 30px :D which makes sense.

Comment: 30px not 30pt, do you have the others in pc too, I'm not sure about iPads either. Why does it make sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited again for iPad findings.
I can't seem to find online info of this gap :P . Damn.

Comment: I'm confused. I can use these values along with the screen sizes I have provided above and make wide images. However these will get resized in the App Store app. And those values you have provided are from the App Store. So the gap values I need will be different / bigger ?